# "pyinstaller" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом. Хотя он есть в pip list

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: При вводе в консоль pyinstaller пишет, что он не является внутренней программой.]
Pip пишет, что pyinstaller установлен, но консоль пишет обратное. При установке нажал add to Path и вручную добавил тоже, думал, что сработает, но нет.

Answer (score 1):

Сам решил свой же вопрос. Pyinstaller оказался на другой части диска в папке appdata, а не в program files. Добавил папку с pyinstaller.exe в Path и все заработало.